How to use Body Text Indent with styles in Word to adjust to different indents for different outline levels?
I have created custom styles for headings in Word. These headings indent at different levels. I would like the text that follows each heading to indent directly under each heading level. When I go in to modify each style, under "style for the following paragraph" I can choose Body Text Indent, but it only works for the FIRST indented style and not the others. There is also a body style indent 2 and 3, but they don't work either and I can't see where to modify the indent for the following paragraph.

You want custom Body Text styles (paragraph styles) to follow each of the heading styles.
Take a look at my free download: Outline Heading Styles Global Stylesheet for examples. https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#GlobalStylesheet
It has nine different body text styles, each with a different indent and each set to follow a numbered heading style of a different level.
You should have each of them set to follow itself with the same body text style.
You may also want to look at my page on Outlining in Microsoft Word.
https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm
